# How to assign time in such format 00:00:00.000 to X axis in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

My problem is that I don't know how to assign time in such format 00:00:00.000 to X axis in JFreeChart.

I'm writing an application which will get the data from CSV file where the columns look like this:

> time accelerationX accelerationY accelerationZ

I looked for example but I didn't find anything which might help me.

My code:

```
public ChartService() {

        final CombinedDomainXYPlot plot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(new DateAxis("Time"));
        this.datasets = new TimeSeriesCollection[SUBPLOT_COUNT];

        for (int i = 0; i < SUBPLOT_COUNT; i++) {
            this.lastValue[i] = 100.0;
            final TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(Y_AXIS_TITLES[i], Millisecond.class);
           // this.series.add(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss.mmm"), 0.2222);

            this.datasets[i] = new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
            final NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis(Y_AXIS_TITLES[i]);
            rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
            final XYPlot subplot = new XYPlot(
                    this.datasets[i], null, rangeAxis, new StandardXYItemRenderer()
            );
            subplot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
            subplot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
            subplot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
            plot.add(subplot);
        }

        final JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Dynamic Data Demo 3", plot);

        chart.setBorderPaint(Color.black);
        chart.setBorderVisible(true);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        final ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setAutoRange(true);
        axis.setFixedAutoRange(60000.0);  // 60 seconds

        final JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        content.add(chartPanel);

        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(790, 620));
        chartPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        this.add(content);

    }
```

Please help !!!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you wan't legends to appear in given format or do you want to convert data in given format to timestamp object that Jfree chart will understand?

Comment: I want to convert time in such format 00:00:00.000 to object that JFreeChart will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String s = "10:00:00.000";
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:SS.SSS");

    Date parsedDate = f.parse(s);
```

You can convert the given time to date as above and then you can use the Date object to create  http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/data/time/Millisecond.html#Millisecond:Date

Comment: +1 for `RegularTimePeriod`; also consider `f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))`.